# How to implement Silverlight in Joomla?

Tags: silverlight, joomla

I have a web-site running under Joomla on GoDaddy hosting.

I want to add compiled Silverlight game (.xap file) to an article.

What should I do to do that?

Comment: Silverlight can be added even to an html page. So if you have access to mark-up - it is possible. But I've never worked with Joomla so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You embed Silverlight just like you do Flash. Depending on the editor you are using, there is likely a media insertion button where you simply put the URL of the content you want to run. Microsoft has detailed information here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089(v=vs.95).aspx